# React Native Base Card Image rounded corners not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I have these cards with an image. Now, I would like the corners to be rounded, however I am currently not finding a way to round them  does not work

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('OffersScreen', {offers: offersArray } ) }>
    <Card  style={{height: 190, width: 190, margin: 0, padding: 0, justifyContent:'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <CardItem cardBody>
          <ImageBackground source={path} style={{ width: 190, height: 190, flex: 1, resizeMode: 'contain'}}/>
          <Text style={styles.textContent}>{ category['category_name'] }</Text>
        </CardItem>
    </Card>
  </TouchableOpacity>);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use borderRadius property to make rounded corners.

In some cases, overflow hidden can also help.

Comment: I tried adding it in the style of both the Card and the CardItem, both didn't do anything

Comment: Try to add in into TouchableOpacity, maybe overflow hidden would help

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do in this case is to add a `borderRadius` to your `<Card />` Component.
The `borderRadius` takes an integer. The higher the integer the more rounded your corners will be. Try this:

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('OffersScreen', {offers: offersArray } ) }>
    <Card  style={{height: 190, width: 190, margin: 0, padding: 0, justifyContent:'center', alignItems: 'center',  borderRadius: 45 }}>
      <CardItem cardBody>
          <ImageBackground source={path} style={{ width: 190, height: 190, flex: 1, resizeMode: 'contain'}}/>
          <Text style={styles.textContent}>{ category['category_name'] }</Text>
        </CardItem>
    </Card>
  </TouchableOpacity>);
```